# Any way to remove duplicate term IEEE from bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, ieeetran

#### Sample Code

```
\begin{document}
% ....
% References
{\small
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\bibliography{Thesis_Main}
}
\end{document}
```

### Bib file

```
@inproceedings{ref20,
  title={Passive RFID for intelligent transportation systems},
  author={Ali, Kashif and Hassanein, Hossam},
  booktitle={2009 6th IEEE Consumer Communications and Networking Conference},
  pages={1--2},
  year={2009},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{ref21,
  title={A security and privacy enhanced protection scheme for secure 900MHz UHF RFID reader on mobile phone},
  author={Park, Namje and Lee, Haedong and Kim, Howon and Won, Dongho},
  booktitle={2006 IEEE International Symposium on Consumer Electronics},
  pages={1--5},
  year={2007},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

### Output

[image]

But my supervisor asked me to remove term 'IEEE' from yellow marked places of items for whose the term appears anywhere in the text before that yellow mark (example shown as red underlines). **Any way to remove duplicate term IEEE from bibliography?**

Comment: simplest is presumably just to delete the organization key

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that will require manual inspection :(

Comment: unless you have tens of thousands of entries in your bibliography how long will it take? less time than it takes to write the above question surely. getting bibtex to check that the organisation value isn't a substring of one of the other keys would take a lot longer to code.

Comment: @David i agree that will take less time to manually fix It up. The post is to learn if there is any way to automate this so that it can be used in future as well as it can reduce chances of missing for new entries. I hope you get the purpose.

Comment: You could go into the bst file of your style (I don't know which style you're using since the code snippet is not a MWE) and change it so that it will not print the organization.

Comment: @Elad thanks but the Organization name is required to show if that name is not appeared in the name of the conference as substring. In that case i need a conditional configuration.

Comment: In that case you can edit the `bst` so that you'd add an `if` to check whether the organization string appears in the `booktitle`. That is not a trivial feat and you're better off manually changing the bib file...

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment on the post. This is not an answer, but can be useful: use the find and replace key in the editor for the .bib file, then replace organization by %organization. I had the same issues earlier, the following trick goes well. You can revert back the organization field anytime. Who has the authority, please move it to the comment section.